# What is the fastest way to add a new IPv4 address on a windows computer using c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, ipv4

I have been using the [`AddIPAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-addipaddress) function to add a new IP address, but there is a ~4 second delay before the address is usable for communications and port binding.

I have looked into other ways of adding an IP, and came across a method that used the `std::system()` function to run a `Netsh interface ipv4 add address` command, and that also adds a usable IP but has the same issue of taking ~4 seconds before the added IP is usable. I have also tried using the `Netsh interface ipv4 set address` command to set the IP address, but again it has the same ~4 second delay before it is usable.

So, I'm curious, is there a different way of adding (or setting) an IP address on a Windows machine through C++ that I may have not found? Or, is this delay unavoidable because of something out of my control?

I do not need this new IP address to be available instantly, anything that can shorten this time to under 2 seconds should work. Also, I would prefer a way that keeps the IP address even after the computer is power cycled, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: Exist only one way - call concrete winapi. Probably exactly AddIPAddress in concrete case. All another way is senseless here - it used a lot of extra code, for finally call winapi

Comment: It's probably looking for a free address.  That takes time, because it has to give other machines on the subnet time to respond.  So you probably can't (and wouldn't want to) make it any faster.

Comment: This screams XY problem to me. I am confused at the reason for this need. Do you really need to add IP additional addresses to your PC that often that 4 seconds is a problem? Is this for some type of testing? Or are you trying to solve some PC networking problem through code?

Comment: Don't use `std::system` unless you want a world of hurt in the form of security problems. Also, why would you outsource your problem to some third party code?

Comment: @PaulSanders Well, no, it isn't, the IP address is supplied by the caller, but it will certainly take a finite time for ARP and RARP and all that to establish the address on the network.

Answer (score 1):

As comments said, use concrete *winapi* for Windows. Don't add a new level of complexity.

Also, it's normal for functions to take time to work.

By the way, according to [AddIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-addipaddress), for another way

> to create an IPv4 address that persists, the EnableStatic method of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Class in the Windows Management
> Instrumentation (WMI) controls may be used.